# Changing notes validation in Joi-Browser

Tags: reactjs, validation, registration, joi

I have auto comments in joi-browser and I would like to change them but I can't seem to do it.
I want all the notes will be in my language and not in english Like appear in the line of  errors.name.
Where I wrong?

How look like my code in the client:

```
import React from "react";
import Form from "./../common/Form/Form";
import PageHeader from "./../common/pageHeader";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { getCurrentUser, login, signup } from "../../services/userService";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Joi from "joi-browser";

class Signup extends Form {
  state = {
    data: {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
    errors: {},
  };

  schema = {
    name: Joi.string().min(2).required().label("שם"),
    email: Joi.string().email().required().label('דוא"ל'),
    password: Joi.string()
      .min(8)
      .regex(/[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-={}';":|,.<>?]+/)
      .required()
      .label("סיסמה"),
  };

  validate(data) {
    const errors = {};

    console.log("Validating data:", data);

    if (!data.name || data.name.length < 2) {
      errors.name = "נדרש שם באורך של לפחות 2 תווים.";
    }

    if (
      !data.email ||
      !/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/.test(data.email)
    ) {
      errors.email = 'נדרש דוא"ל חוקי.';
    }

    if (!data.password || data.password.length < 8) {
      errors.password = "נדרשת סיסמה באורך של לפחות 8 תווים.";
    }

    if (!/[a-z]/.test(data.password)) {
      errors.password = `${
        errors.password || ""
      } הסיסמה צריכה להכיל לפחות אות קטנה אחת.`;
    }

    if (!/[A-Z]/.test(data.password)) {
      errors.password = `${
        errors.password || ""
      } הסיסמה צריכה להכיל לפחות אות גדולה אחת.`;
    }

    if (!/[0-9]/.test(data.password)) {
      errors.password = `${
        errors.password || ""
      } הסיסמה צריכה להכיל לפחות ספרה אחת.`;
    }

    if (!/[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{};':"\\|,.<>/?]+/.test(data.password)) {
      errors.password = `${
        errors.password || ""
      } הסיסמה צריכה להכיל לפחות תו מיוחד אחד.`;
    }

    return Object.keys(errors).length === 0 ? null : errors;
  }

  doSubmit = async () => {
    console.log("doSubmit is being called"); // הוסף כאן
    try {
      console.log("Entering try block in doSubmit");
      const user = { ...this.state.data };
      console.log("User signed up successfully");
      await signup(user);
      toast.success(`${user.name} נרשמת בהצלחה`);
      delete user.name;
      await login(user);
      console.log("User logged in successfully");
      window.location = "/";
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Entering catch block in doSubmit", error);
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 400) {
        this.setState({
          errors: { email: "המשתמש קיים כבר במערכת" },
        });
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    console.log("Render method of Signup is called");
    const user = getCurrentUser();
    if (user) return <Navigate replace to="/" />;

    return (
      <div style={{ minHeight: "85vh" }} className="container-fluid pb-4">
        <div className="container">
          <PageHeader title="הרשמה" subTitle="" />
          <div className="center">
            <form
              onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              autoComplete="off"
              method="POST"
              style={{ marginLeft: "250px", direction: "rtl" }}
              className="col-12 col-md-10 col-xl-6"
            >
              {this.renderInput("name", "שם:")}
              {this.renderInput("email", "מייל:", "email")}
              {this.renderInput("password", "סיסמה:", "password")}
              {this.renderButton("הרשמה", "btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-2 col-12")}
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Signup;
```

and it's my end point in the server:

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validateRegistration(req.body);
  if (error) {
    console.log(chalk.redBright(error.details[0].message));
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  }

  let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  console.log("User object before passing to generateAuthToken:", user);
  if (user) {
    console.log(chalk.redBright("Registration Error: User already registered"));
    return res.status(400).send("User already registered.");
  }

  user = new User(
    _.pick(req.body, ["name", "email", "password", "biz", "cards"])
  );

  user.password = generateHashPassword(user.password);
  await user.save();
  res.send(_.pick(user, ["_id", "name", "email"]));
});
```

I'd glad to know how can I change the notes
Thank You